# How to add external url existing laravel blade file with play button

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I have a site with a list of games ( tiled on the index page)
when a user clicks the image the current url is shown on the browser something like http://example.com/game/sweetbanabas?api_exit=
the game currently reside in the /public/games directory.

Now I have the game.blade.php as such:

```
<div class="grid-item grid-item--height2 grid-item--width2">
<div class="grid__content games">
    <div class="games__item">
        <div class="games__content">
            <img src="{{ $game->name ? '/frontend/Default/ico/' . $game->name . '.jpg' : '' }}" alt="{{ $game->title }}">
            @if($game->jackpot)
                <span class="label label-d label--left">
       {{ number_format($game->jackpot->balance, 2,".","") }} {{ $currency }}
      </span>
            @endif
            @if($game->label)
                <span class="label @if($game->label == 'New')label-b @elseif($game->label == 'Hot')label-g @else label-d @endif">{{ mb_strtoupper($game->label) }}</span>
            @endif
            <a href="{{ route('frontend.game.go', $game->name) }}?api_exit=/" class="play-btn btn">Play</a>
            <span class="game-name">{{ $game->title }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I would like to put my /games folder on another server. in what part of the href` would I add the url to the external server?

Thank you for any pointers

Answer (score 0):

You should put new url in anchor tag....

**From**

```
<a href="{{ route('frontend.game.go', $game->name) }}?api_exit=/" class="play-btn btn">Play</a>
```

**To**

```
<a href="Your New URL goes here" class="play-btn btn">Play</a>
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: Im not sure its that simple???? I have 5 games in a list.blade.php....so if i click each tile separately i see /game/sweetbananas1?api_exit=/,/game/sweetbananas2?api_exit=/,/game/sweetbananas3?api_exit=/ etc...

Comment: if you have multiple games in list page, you should use jQuery to get the appropriate URL.